# How can I pass data from a component array to an another component with props?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I need a little help. I'm working on a project that uses Class Components in React and I got stuck with a issue.

How can I pass **datas** using props?

For example, imagine that I have one Component that have an array in the state:

```
import React,{Component} from "react";


class CarList extends Component{
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    carList: ['Jeep', 'Kwid','HB20','Ônix', 'Prisma', 'Gol quadrado']
  }
  }


render(){
    return(
      <div>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default CarList;
```

And now I have to call this array in a Option Tag inside a Select Tag.

Let's imagine this component Bellow:

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import CarList from "./components/Datas";


class App extends Component{



render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <p>I got it! Here is the car list:</p>
      <select>
        {this.state.CarList.map(  (item,x)=>{
          return(
            <option key={x}>{item}</option>
          )
        })}
      </select>
    
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default App;
```

This piece of code does not work.
the console.log says: "Uncaught TypeError: this.state is null"

I know that I could create a div with my datas and call with , but I have to use props to pass the datas between the Components.

**How can I create a callback function using props to resolve this?**

Hi!

I tried to call using this.state, but I got "this.state is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass your data as a props you have to pass it to your child component like this from your parent component :

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    carList: [],
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      carList: ['Jeep', 'Kwid', 'HB20', 'Ônix', 'Prisma', 'Gol quadrado'],
    };
  }

  render() {;
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent carList={this.state.carList || []} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and then it is accessible in your child component with `this.props`.

you can use this props in child component like this:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.carList.map((cars, index) => {
          return (
            <span key={index}>
              {cars}
              <br />
            </span>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit -

if you want to see source code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ddcylu?file=Parent.tsx